# access the value of search box in sharepoint search results page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I wanted to access the search box value with the help of jQuery in my search results  page , in page load event.

Answer (score 6):

When you perform search, search box value get added in querystring of search URL.
For e.g. something like below

```
/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?u=url&k=searchboxvalue
```

You can use below script to get value of search box from the URL

```
<script language="javascript">

//First we have to call the EnsureSetup method
JSRequest.EnsureSetup();

searchvalue = JSRequest.QueryString["k"];//where k is querystring parameter

</script>
```

Comment: May I know ,why are we using jsrequest.ensure setup()? Is that Mandatory . unaware of this API in JS. Al's do I need to refer any otheR js files for getting this ensuresetup() ?

Comment: You can find more information on JSRequest here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20820.sharepoint-2010-about-jsrequest.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery way of getting the search box's value would be:

```
var initialValue = $('#searchBox').val();
```

and to set a new value for the search box:

```
$('#searchBox').val(newValue);
```

You need to define the search box's ID to the `'#searchBox'`, as there are search boxes in different contexts of SharePoint.

Note that you don't need jQuery to for this. To e.g. set the value, you could just use:

```
document.getElementById('searchBox').value
```